# What can I use to ping a site on a specific port and see if it's online or not?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, my friend has a Minecraft server running out there. I want our Discord Bot to ping the server's IP, e.g myfriendsserver.mc . Now, I want it to check if the server is online or not. If it's online, I want to have the bot ping that it's online, else it's going to say the server is offline.

I believe the code is going to be fairly simple, but I'm unsure about how exactly I should approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

The minecraft server will likely utilize the WSS server already, you would just need the client to connect to it, get past hand-shake and then send pong anytime the server sends ping.

This will keep a heart-beat going and from there at any-point it takes to long to get a response we call it offline till next-connection.

---

There's certainly many methods for checking connection of the server, another method could be utilizing an HTTP server and say at location http://127.0.0.1/get-status it'd output you the following in JSON.

```
{"status":"online"}
```

or even

```
{"status":"busy too many requests"}
```

I'd probably for simplicity utilize the WebSockets as they should already be in use adaptation would be minimal.

Comment: Assuming the users authenticate prior to using WSS; this is how they get the hand-shake. You may need to modify or "force"  credentials to apply this tracker if something along the lines is not already implemented. :)

Comment: @blanknameforenow I'm kind of a beginner, so I don't exactly know what you mean but, I'll try out what you suggested.